# How do I write a group_concat function in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to re-write this mysql query in SQLAlchemy:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `post_id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `post_name` VARCHAR(255)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `post_tags` (
    `tag_id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tag_name` VARCHAR(255)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `post_tags_map` (
    `map_id` INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `post_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `tags_id` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY `post_id` REFERENCES `posts` (`post_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY `post_id` REFERENCES `post_tags` (`tag_id`)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    posts.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT( post_tags.tag_name order by post_tags.tag_name ) AS tags

  FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_tags_map
      ON posts_tags_map.post_id = posts.post_id
    LEFT JOIN post_tags
      ON posts_tags_map.tags_id = posts_tags.tag_id

  WHERE posts.post_id = 1
  GROUP BY post_id
```

Here's what I have, but I keep getting:

```
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPARATOR /))

rows = DBSession.query(Posts,func.group_concat(Post_Tags.tag_name.op('SEPARATOR')(literal_column('/')))).outerjoin(PostsTagsMap,Posts.post_id==PostsTagsMap.post_id).outerjoin(Post_Tags,PostsTagsMap.tags_id==Post_Tags.tag_id).group_by(Posts.post_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a custom function element seems the easiest way to take care of the `group_concat` method.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler


class group_concat(expression.FunctionElement):
    name = "group_concat"


@compiler.compiles(group_concat, 'mysql')
def _group_concat_mysql(element, compiler, **kw):
    if len(element.clauses) == 2:
        separator = compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[1])
    else:
        separator = ','

    return 'GROUP_CONCAT(%s SEPARATOR %s)'.format(
        compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[0]),
        separator,
    )
```

And use it something like this:

```
query = select([
    table.c.some_column,
    expression.label(
        'grouped column',
        group_concat(
            table.c.some_oter_column,
            ' separator ',
        ),
    ),
]).group_by(table.c.some_column)
```

Answer (score 6):

Wasted a lot of time testing the above examples and other random sources to find out how to change the standard delimiting character `","` in the `func.group_concat()` ... only to then follow intuition and find out that the syntax works exactly as you would anticipate: pass your delimiting character as an argument.
Such as:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
#write the query: db.session.query(...
...func.group_concat(Table.column_name, "; ")
```

So, modifying a previous answer's example:

```
DBSession.query(
   Posts, 
   func.group_concat(Post_Tags.tag_name, "/"))<...>
```

Note: this is with Python 3.5, SQLite 3, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2 (SQLAlchemy 1.0.13 installed)

Comment: This doesn't work. It does "compile" to `GROUP_CONCAT(name, "; ")` that will actually append "; " to every record, but leave the default "," separator

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you did the group_concat bit right:

```
DBSession.query(
   Posts, 
   func.group_concat(Post_Tags.tag_name.op('SEPARATOR')(literal_column('/'))))<...>
```

I am not sure what exactly is going on, as it seems your schema is not valid, your query has misspelled table names, and judging by the error, you tried to feed python code into mysql.

For those who, like me, found this page while googling, the code bit above should be helpful, also there is the source, apparently: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sqlalchemy/eNbOoRJ425s/bScfQVat15EJ

Comment: The `literal_column` calls seems necessary here, it works using `.op('separator')('/')`

Comment: `literal_column` doesn't quote the separator so at least on MariaDB it will result in a syntax error.  Passing the separator as '/' or `literal('/')` both produce a syntactically correct statement.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get this working.

```
>>> str(func.group_concat(Keyword.text.op('separator')(text('","'))))
'group_concat(keywords.text separator ",")'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `literal_column(' = ')` but MYSQL would parse it into `separator =` other than `separator '='`, so I add triple quotes before and after as `literal_column("""' = '""")` which finally works.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205850/how-do-i-write-a-group-concat-function-in-sqlalchemy#comment129728494_21234721).