# how to group selection from other table as one column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

here is two tables:

a:

```
+-----+------------------------+
| id  | conten                 | 
+-----+------------------------+
| 1   | q.                     |
| 2   | q.                     |
| 3   | s.                     |
| 4   | g                      |
| 1   | a                      |
| 2   | a                      |
+-----+------------------------+
```

b:

```
+-----+------------------------+
| id  | type                   | 
+-----+------------------------+
| 1   | I.                     |
| 2   | II.                    |
| 3   | III.                   |
| 4   | IV                     |
| 5   | V                      |
| 6   | VI                     |
+-----+------------------------+
```

Is there a way to select from a and b so that for one id `2`, there will be one additional field that groups all content from that id? the select result should be something like this:

```
+-----+------------------------+-----------+
| id  | type                   | contents  |
+-----+------------------------+-----------+
| 2   |I.                      | q,a       |
+-----+------------------------+-----------+
```

**Edited**
btw, if there is a way to do it by sqlahcmey, that would be sweet.

Comment: Yes GROUP_CONCAT with a GROUP

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: @Eli mysql. sorry for wrong tag

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.id, b.type, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(a.conten), '') AS contents
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id
```

See [How do I write a group_concat function in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205850/how-do-i-write-a-group-concat-function-in-sqlalchemy) for how to translate `GROUP_CONCAT` to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Sorry to bother you @barmar But for what is the usage of IFNULL before the group_concat ? You have also single quotes. Just curious since it is new and want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: If there are no matching rows in table `b`, `GROUP_CONCAT()` will return `NULL`. This converts that null value into an empty string.

Comment: Oops, I got the tables backwards, fixed it.

Comment: thanks for the information. There is also a name what should be fixed in the group_concat. I was unable to edit it. The colomn of a is not contents but conten.

Comment: I thought that was a typo in the question.

Comment: idk like it is kinda weird for me to put duplicate id numbers in tables.

Comment: @Noob `a.id` is actually a poorly named FK to `b.id`, it's not the primary key of `a`.

Comment: I understand it but why not updating the conten colomn instead of creating a extra row ?

Comment: @Noob Putting multiple values in a single column is a violation of normalization rules.

Comment: so this is the best solution ? Because i thought that insert duplicate id numbers are also a violation of normalization

Comment: They aren't duplicate IDs. They're foreign keys in a one-to-many relationship.